# Two contradictory errors about Type mismatch in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion

What on earth could be causing this? I'm getting two contradicting errors on one method I'm trying to create in a java program

```
public void numberOfTrianglesIncidentToVertex(){
  for(List<Integer> pairs: neighbors.get(2)){     // Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Integer to List<Integer>

  }
    int fail = neighbors.get(2);       // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Integer> to int
}
```

The neighbors variable is declared in a super class as follows:

```
List<List<Integer>> neighbors 
= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

I don't know why it would tell me on one line that its an Integer and can't be converted to a List of integers and then on the very next line just change its mind and say the exact opposite. which is it?

Comment: Ah! Wait, are you sure you are getting that error message on for loop. I suspect you should get a different error. Imcompatible type from `Integer` to `String`. Can you confirm?

Comment: I just updated the question. I had changed that type messing around with it and failed to put it back before copying the method for the question. My apologies, The question is now exactly as it should be.

Comment: These errors are not contradictory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your declaration of *neighbors*, the following invocation:

```
neighbors.get(2);
```

will give you a `List<Integer>`.

Now in 1<sup>st</sup> snippet, you are trying to iterate over the return value. So, when you iterate over `List<Integer>`, you get back values of type `Integer`. And you are using `List<Integer>` type loop variable. Hence that error message. You can't assign an `Integer` reference to a `List<Integer>` reference.

You should change your loop to:

```
for(int val: neighbors.get(2)) {  // 'int' works in place of 'Integer', due to unboxing
}
```

However, if you iterate on `neighbors`, your loop will work fine, because then you will get `List<Integer>` reference on iterating.

```
for(List<Integer> val: neighbors) { 
}
```

---

In 2<sup>nd</sup> snippet, you are directly assigning the fetched value - `List<Integer>` to an `int` primitive. Which obviously you can't do. They aren't at all compatible. Hence the error message.
The assignment should be like:

```
List<Integer> list = neighbors.get(2);
```

Comment: yes, the second snippet was mainly out of frustration, and being that the error (i thought) was suggesting it was an integer, i figured I'd test that obviously flawed theory.

Comment: Thank you, my confusion was with the list of lists. and I see now the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 neighbors.get(2)
```

returns you `List<Integer>`. Second warning is clear about that.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Integer to List

To iterate over this list you'll need to iterate over i - integer.

```
 for(Integer pairs: neighbors.get(2))
```